# snakemake workflow on split files

Tags: python, snakemake

Perhaps this question has already been answered but I could not come up with the correct query to find it...

I have a big file that needs to be analyzed. In order to do this quickly, I first split the big file into multiple small files and do my analysis on each of them separately in parallel. For this, I have something like this:

```
rule all:
    input:
        'bigfile.{wildcards.partnum}.out',

rule split_big_file:
    input: 'bigfile'
    output: touch('splitting_file.done')
    shell: 'split {input}'

rule process_small_files:
    input: 
        small_file = 'bigfile.{wildcards.partnum}',
        done = 'splitting_file.done'
    output: 'bigfile.{wildcards.partnum}.out'
    shell:
        'some_command {input.small_file} > {output}'
```

The rule `split_big_file` uses `split` command and generates files that have filenames like `bigfile.001, bigfile.002, etc`. I use `touch('splitting_file.done')` in the rule `split_big_file` to make sure that the next rule `process_small_files` does not start before it finishes. When I try to run this, I get a `Missing input files for rule process_small_files` error. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 4):

The rule "process_small_files" sees that it needs a file such as bigfile.001, but as far as snakemake knows, no rule in the workflow can make that file. While split_big_file will make that file, in the "output" section it only states that it will make the file "splitting_file.done" so snakemake doesn't think the workflow can make bigfile.001 and assumes it should already exist.

Because the split command makes a different number of files depending on the size of the input file, you will need to use the dynamic files feature of snakemake: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#dynamic-files

Comment: When I use `dynamic`, how can I make `process_small_files` wait until `split_big_file` has finished? I cannot use my `touch('splitting_file.done')` trick because "A rule with dynamic output may not define any non-dynamic output files." And when I drop the `splitting_file.done` output it does not wait until the `split_big_file` rule hasn't finished.

Comment: Note that dynamic files have been superseded by [checkpoints](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution)