# How to implement splitting of files in snakemake when number of files is known

Tags: snakemake

### Context

`rule A` uses the `split` command in a `shell` directive.
The number of files generated by `rule A` depends on a user specified value from the config and is thus known.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674470/snakemake-workflow-on-split-files) there is a difference because the number of output files is unknown, but there is a reference to the `dynamic()` keyword. Apparently this has been replaced by the use of `checkpoint`. Is this really the correct way to go in this scenario? There is also something like `scattergatter` but the example is not clear to me.

### Code

```
chunks = config["chunks"]
sample_list = ["S1", "S2"]

rule all:
    input:
       expand("{sample}_chunk_{chunk}_done_something.tsv", sample=sample_list, 
             chunk=[f"{i}".zfill(len(str(chunks))-1) for i in range(0, chunks)])

rule A:
    input:
        "input_file_{sample}.tsv"
    output:
        # the user defined number of chunks, how to specify these?
    params: chunks=chunks
    shell:
        "split -n {params.chunks} --numeric-suffixes=1 --additional-suffix=.tsv {input[0]} some_prefix_{wildcards.sample}_"

rule B: 
    input:
        "some_prefix_{sample}_{chunk}.tsv"
    output:
        "{sample}_chunk_{chunk}_done_something.tsv"
    shell:
        "#Do something"
```

### Attempts

I tried using a checkpoint with an `input function` for `rule B` and using `directory()` in `rule A`. However using directory results in `SyntaxError in line 253 of MySnakefile: Unexpected keyword directory in rule definition (Snakefile, line 253)` and even if that would not throw an error, I don't know how to get `chunks` into this input function since it is not a wildcard.

How to implement the splitting of an input file best in Snakemake?

Comment: Could you use something like `expand(out_{chunk},chunk=CHUNK)` where outside the rules, you have defined a list `CHUNK` based on your `params.chunks`

Comment: @Tyberius not sure if I understand you completely. But `expand()` can never be used under the `output:` directive right?

Comment: `expand` is just python function defined by Snakemake, you should be able to use it anywhere in your Snakefile. This input ran just fine for me using a `blank` file containing three lines ```INDEX=["aa","ab","ac"]

rule all:
    input:
        "blank"
    output:
        expand("blank{ind}",ind=INDEX)
    run:
        shell("split --number=3 blank blank") ```

Comment: Thanks @Tyberius, somehow the expand function is not working for me. Which is weird as the directory function isn't working either. Snakemake v6.2.0 issue? The solution provided by dofree did work though, so I implemented that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the number of chunks is known beforehand, you can set the number of output files in `rule A` from the chunks parameter using an array:

```
rule A:
    ...
    output:
        chunks = ["some_prefix_{{sample}}_{02d}.tsv".format(x+1) for x in range(chunks)]
```

With `chunks = 2`, this would expand to `chunks = ["some_prefix_{sample}_01.tsv", "some_prefix_{sample}_02.tsv"]`, matching the synatx of the `split` output. The `{sample}` wildcard will be filled-in with Snakemake's standard wildcard replacement.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. Good to have confirmed that the way to go is the "simple" route and there is no need for a construction with input functions. Still weird that both my expand and directory keywords don't work.